# Matrices K and V in the decoder part in the transformer model?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, machine-translation

There is something I do not get in the illustrated transformer article from Jay Alamar (http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/). In the decoder side paragraph, he said

> The encoder start by processing the input sequence. The output of the
>   top encoder is then transformed into a set of attention vectors K and
>   V.

**How the hell do we compute those K and V?**. If i well understood, the output of the encoder is a matrice (Number of words x Embedding Length). So where those K and V come from please?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By linear projections, one projection per attention head later used in the encoder-decoder attention.

To be consistent with the notation in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf), it would better to say that in the encoder-decoder attention $K = V$ which are the final states of the encoder and $Q$ are decoder states from a particular layer. They are used as input of the $\text{MultiHead}$ (unnumbered equation on top of page 5) function where they are projected for individual heads.

[image]

So in the individual head computation according to Equation 1:

[image]

it is indeed true $K$ and $V$ are linear projections of the final encoder states (outputs of the top encoder layer).

Comment: Finally I think I understand the whole thing. Thank you Sir! Very nice from you!